# How to use two timers simultaneously to control 2 servo motors

Tags: pic, pwm, servo

im very new to PIC. Im trying to control 2 servo motors for the wheel of my robot. Im using PIC16f877A MCU, [servo motor](http://rchobbies.com.au/store/product_info.php?products_id=74991) and 4 mhz crystal oscillator. I use mikroC compiler.

Actually i already have a code here by using polling with delays:

```
 while(1)
 {
     //right wheel rotate clockwise;
     PORTC.F1 = 1;
     delay_us(1748);
     PORTC.F1 = 0;
     delay_us(18252);

     //left wheel rotate counter-clockwise
     PORTC.F2 = 1;
     delay_us(1458);
     PORTC.F2 = 0;
     delay_us(18542);
  }
```

This lines of code actually works, but sometimes the other wheel runs first, making the robot run in incorrect position. Can you suggest any method aside from just polling?  Many say that using interrupt is better and accurate than polling. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29), it's just toggling the outputs with software delays.

RC servos expect to see pulses at a rate of about 50 times per second. The `While(1)` loop should take 20ms, so remove the `delay_us(18252)` and change the `delay_us(18542)` to `delay_us(16794)`. Now the loop will take just over 20ms and the second servo will receive its pulse immediately after the first, rather than 20ms later.

If no interrupts are active then this code should produce very stable pulses. If you still get unexpected movements then the cause is external, eg. inconsistent servo response or bad power supply.

Comment: Ahh ok, i thought that technique is called polling. Im not using any interrupt as of now. I will try this sir and feedback later. Thank you sir

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback, so busy this few past days. The delay you suggested sir works like a charm. Im using it now. Thank you for the help.